# Set Excel Column to Text (Exporting Data in DataGridView to Excel)

Tags: c#, excel, winforms, datagridview

I'm exporting data from DataGridView to Excel. Everything works great but when a data in columns have, for example: 000115455, Excel is ignoring the '0' and inserting 115455. I try next:

- Format the column in DataTable before Fill DataGridView
- Casting data retrieve from database as VARCHAR.
- Format the column in DataGridView after Fill.
- Using Range.EntireColumn, Range.Cells.NumberFormat and other ways in my method.

None of this works!

Below the piece of code that export to excel and save the file

```
ExcelApp = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();
ExcelLibro = ExcelApp.Workbooks.Add(misDatos);
ExcelHoja = (Excel.Worksheet)ExcelLibro.Worksheets.get_Item(1);
Excel.Range rangoHoja = (Excel.Range)ExcelHoja.Cells[1, 1];
rangoHoja.Select();
ExcelHoja.PasteSpecial(rangoHoja, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, true);
ExcelLibro.SaveAs(opcionSFD.FileName, 
                                  Excel.XlFileFormat.xlWorkbookNormal,
                                  misDatos,
                                  misDatos, 
                                  misDatos, 
                                  misDatos, 
                                  Excel.XlSaveAsAccessMode.xlExclusive, 
                                  misDatos, 
                                  misDatos, 
                                  misDatos, 
                                  misDatos,
                                  misDatos);

                ExcelApp.DisplayAlerts = true;
                ExcelLibro.Close(true, misDatos, misDatos);
                ExcelApp.Quit();
```

What I can do?

Answer (score 0):

This works for me:

Before call `ExcelHoja.PasteSpecial(...)` add this line:

```
rangoHoja.NumberFormat = "@";
```

This sets cell's format to *Text*.

```
...
rangoHoja.Select();
rangoHoja.NumberFormat = "@"; //Added Line    
ExcelHoja.PasteSpecial(...);
...
```

Hope this helps